# C++14 TS functionality and GCC 4.8

Tags: c++, c++14

I would like to try some of the new features that will make it to the C++2014 [revision](http://isocpp.org/std/status) like `std::make_unique` and the `std::filesystem` functionnalities. I use ubuntu 14.04 and GCC/G++ 4.8  (with libstdc++-4.8-dev installed), and the flag `-std=c++1y` set. But there is no `std::make_unique` when including `<tr1/memory>`, and no `<experimental/...>` headers.
What do I need to do to be able to use some of those new features ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<tr1/memory>` is not a C++14 standard header. You simply want `<memory>`. Same for `<dynarray>`.

However, neither are supported in GCC 4.8. You need to upgrade to GCC 4.9 or clang 5.

The GCC compiler support status for C++1y can be checked [on the Language Features status page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html), and the library support on the [Library Support status page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2014).

Comment: I tried that already but I don't have any `<dynarray>` header (I guess because it won't make it to the C++14). But yet, using `<memory>` still fails when try to use `std::make_unique`. I will try clang or g++4.9 then. Any advice on how to use some TS features like <std::file_system> or nothing has been implemented yet by the compiler writers ?

Comment: @Athanase g++ 4.9 does not implement `std::dynarray`, but `std::make_unique` should be available in `<memory>`. It is not available in the 4.8 release. Nothing from `<file_system>` has been implemented yet in g++. The only TS features implemented in g++ 4.9 are `std::optional` and `std::string_view`.

Comment: clang is only a compiler, the standard library is the one shipped with gcc or xcode or visual studio. The llvm project own a new [c++ library](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) subproject but it is mainly for linux or Mac osx for the moment.

Comment: @galop1n True, I kind of muddled them together since I do use libc++ with clang.

Comment: gcc-4.10 just branched.  I'm pretty sure `<dynarray>` will be along within a month or two.  Ditto for `<filesystem>`.  gcc-4.9 has `<optional>` and `<string_view>` and most of the smaller changes in the library.  As for base language gcc-4.9 has auto function return type deduction, binary literals, digit separators.